# Scrbook headings style

Tags: koma-script, classicthesis, scrbook

I am trying to simplify the heading styles of the `scrbook`-class for use in my thesis, but am unable to find a way to stop the headings from being underlined and chapters being marked by their numbers. Here is the class-specification I am using:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
oneside,
headinclude,
footinclude,
headnosepline,
BCOR5mm,
]{scrbook}
```

Below is an example of the current output. What I essentially want to achieve is get rid of the line underneath the chapter title, and the number to the right.

[image: Scrbook Example]

Any thoughts on doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Added MWE:

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
oneside,
headinclude,
footinclude,
headnosepline,
BCOR5mm,
]{scrbook}
\input{structure.tex}
\hyphenation{Fortran hy-phen-ation}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\begin{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Spring \the\year}
\end{titlepage}
\makeatother

\newpage\pagestyle{scrheadings}\pagenumbering{Roman}
\chapter*{Contents}\singlespacing
\tableofcontents
\onehalfspacing
\pagestyle{plain}
\newpage\chapter{Introduction} \label{part:Introduction}
\end{document}
```

**structure.tex**

```
\usepackage[parts,beramono,eulermath,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[round, longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph} {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph} {\parindent}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}%[miktex]%[shell]
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep = comma}
\pgfplotsset{width=\textwidth,compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\makeatletter
\def\thmhead@plain#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{: {\the\thm@notefont#3}}}
\let\thmhead\thmhead@plain
\makeatother
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand{\msout}[1]{\text{\sout{\ensuremath{#1}}}}
\usepackage{chronology}
\usepackage{easy-todo}
\input{PgfplotNan.tex}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{setspace}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{datagloss}
\selectcolormodel{gray}

\newenvironment{blockquote}{%
  \par%
  \em
  \medskip
  \leftskip=4em\rightskip=2em%
  \noindent\ignorespaces}{%
  \par\medskip}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis x label/.append style={
        alias=current axis xlabel
    },
    legend pos/outer south/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend style={
            at={%
                (%
                \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@current axis xlabel}%
                {xticklabel cs:0.5}%
                {current axis xlabel.south}%
                )%
            },
            anchor=north
        }
    }
}
\makeatother

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{black-white-mark}{%
    solid, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray}, mark=*\\%
    dotted, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray}, mark=square*\\%
    densely dotted, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray}, mark=otimes*\\%
    loosely dotted, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray}, mark=triangle*\\%
    dashed, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mark=diamond*\\%
    loosely dashed, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mark=*\\%
    densely dashed, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mark=square*\\%
    dashdotted, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mark=otimes*\\%
    dasdotdotted, every mark/.append style={solid},mark=star\\%
    densely dashdotted,every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mark=diamond*\\%
}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{black-white-nomark}{%
    solid\\%
    dotted\\%
    densely dotted\\%
    loosely dotted\\%
    dashed\\%
    loosely dashed\\%
    densely dashed\\%
    dashdotted\\%
    dasdotdotted\\%
    densely dashdotted\\%
}
\newcommand{\chartstyle}{
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
    1000 sep={},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    % legend style={at={(0,0)}, anchor=north east, align=left}, % Lower left corner
    legend pos=outer south, % Below
    % legend pos=north east, % Top right corner
    cycle list name=black-white-nomark,
}
\newcommand{\nochartstyle}{
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
    1000 sep={},
    ymajorgrids=false,
    grid style=dashed,
    % legend style={at={(0,0)}, anchor=north east, align=left}, % Lower left corner
    legend pos=outer south, % Below
    % legend pos=north east, % Top right corner
    cycle list name=black-white-nomark,
    xlabel={},
    xticklabels={,,}
    ylabel={},
    yticklabels={,,},
    axis y line*=left,
    scaled y ticks = false
}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis} 
\newtheorem{subhyp}{Hypothesis}[hyp]

\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true, breaklinks=true, bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered,
urlcolor=black, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black,
pdftitle={},
pdfauthor={\textcopyright},
pdfsubject={},
pdfkeywords={},
pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX},
pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref and ClassicThesis}
}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I fear somehow, that you're using `scrbook` together with `titlesec` or even `classicthesis`.

Comment: I'm not at the workstation at current, but I do in fact have a vast collage of packages (including classicthesis, and quite possibly titlesec) and solutions that sort of just built as the project went along. I was considering started with a clean template and just input my data again, it's all well-organized as chapters in folders. Why would classicthesis be disadvantageous with scrbook?

Comment: `classicthesis` does many things that are no well, are plain *run you fool*. As long as you know, where `classicthesis` messes up stuff, you are fine. If not, things may work out not as you want.

Comment: I added a MWE, which compiles without error. It is basically as my document appears currently (save a few edits to remove personalia and comments).

Comment: Kick out the `titlesec` stuff and you are fine. Kick out `classicthesis` as well, it defines the appearance of chapter titles as well.  Have you tried `KOMA`-script without any of those stuff?

Comment: I have not, I just recently stumbled over it when I was told that chapter headings are preferable in a thesis, and I was writing in an article class. With the titlesec and classicthesis packages remove I get an error with \c@lofdepth and \c@lotdepth from tocloft.sty.

Comment: Did you clear all help files? Like *.aux, *.toc etc?

Comment: Taking your code and running it, i get errors about files not available. `No room for a new \`dimen'`. Removing all the `titlesec` and classicsthesis stuff will give an error with the next run, but once the auxiliary files are clear, it should work fine. You have a huge (HUGE) amount of packages there, 98% not related to the topic at hand. I bet this is some kind of template that a good soul gave you. I bet didn't know, that this isn't best-practice, it is bad-practice.

Comment: KOMA script provides many many many features to help you using a simple interface. You on the other hand are setting stuff by hand, You want to set the toc singelspaced, that is fine. KOMA gives you quite a simple hook for that. You (or the initiator of that code) is whacking KOMAs definition to death, implementing its own version using a corkscrew and some gaffa tape.

Comment: I did clear the cache (I compile with ShareLatex), but the error persisted. I googled a bit and after adding in the hyperref package (not sure why it was not explicitly called) and removing the subfig package it compiled.

Comment: Is there some quick tutorial or good template for using KOMA to write a thesis? You are right, the template I used in its original form is far removed from what it ended up as (it was a bit limiting for what I needed), and almost all it it are additions added by hand.

Comment: `hyperref` should be loaded last (few exceptions). `classicthesis` is loading it for you, right at the beginning.

Comment: [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) introduces the first steps with LaTeX on KOMA examples. The KOMA manual can be found on your hard drive -> `texdoc koma`

Comment: To get the `tableofcontents` and the other lists singlespaced, use `\AfterTOCHead` as seen in [Set list of content and other lists single spaced](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205121)

Comment: Rather than keep hacking away at the current template and hoping for a suitable outcome, I will take your advice and go with a clean KOMA template. After all, most of the content is already written, and can be input practically anywhere. I found a good thesis template on GitHub: https://github.com/novoid/LaTeX-KOMA-template

As an answer to the original question, I think your initial suggestion of removing `titlesec` and `classicthesis` is sufficient. Would you mind posting it as an answer (SE should have a function to elevate comments to answers)?

Comment: In case you speak german: http://www.komascript.de/latexvorlage

Comment: It was solved by suggestions in these comments,particularly the above of remove ``titlesec`` and ``classicthesis``. I'll add it as an answer, had forgotten about this question some time ago (stresses of actually writing the thesis and all that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments to the question, removing the `titlesec` and `classicthesis` packages solved the problem. In retrospect, it is advisable to choose a complete class earlier, like the suggested KOMA-script, as this will save time with the final product - as opposed to hacking together solutions along the way.

As it happened, I did not have the time to switch classes at the point I was with writing and rewriting content, as well as the formatting which was already much in place, so I went with the suggested solution; and it produced an acceptable final product.